# how to upload pictures to the facebook ads api? error-> Image Resize Failed: the getimagesize function returned false

Tags: php, facebook

I am having trouble to upload pictures to the facebook ads api. the picture is located on the server and i am trying to use curl to get it working. My codes are as shown below but it doesnt work. Any idea why? Thanks

```
$targeting=array('countries'=>array('US'),'gender'=>array('1'));
$creative=array('title'=>'test me','body'=>'this is a test','link_url'=>'http://www.myurl.com','image_file'=>'test.jpg');
$adgroup_spec=array('campaign_id'=>$campaignid,
                    'name'=>'test',
                    'bid_type'=>1,
                    'max_bid'=>10,
                    'targeting'=>$targeting,
                    'creative'=>$creative
                    );
$adgroup_spec=urlencode(json_encode($adgroup_spec));

$path_to_image='@.\test.jpg';

$url="https://api.facebook.com/method/ads.createAdgroups?account_id=$MYACCOUNTID&adgroup_specs=$adgroup_spec&access_token=$accesstoken&$image_file=$path_to_image&format=json";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The image is never created and i get the error -> Image Resize Failed: the getimagesize function returned false

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must specify the image_file parameter

and specify "image_file_name" too.

**Example:**

```
-F "image_file=name.jpg" -F "name.jpg=@./upload.jpg"
```

**Sample Code:**

```
curl -F "type=1" -F "name=name_sample" -F "title=title_sample" -F "body=body_sample" -F "link_url=http://www.sample.co.jp/" -F "image_file=name.jpg" -F "name.jpg=@./upload.jpg" "https://graph.facebook.com/act_id/adcreatives?&access_token=______"
```